TV show or movie in which a man is hiding from an alien and using the reflection on his knife to watch it
I remember watching a TV show or Movie back in the mid 2000s.
The part I can remember is a man hiding behind some rocks and watching an alien in the reflection om his knife. Then some glowing bugs start bothering him, so he starts throwing granola/candy bar pieces to distract the glowing bugs.
That's all I remember.

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BladeReflection has some examples but nothing that appears to match this.
